# Getting window size before adding controls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a custom view with a public function that adds a control as a child of the view, and I want to call it from my activity. The problem is that I need to know the size of the view in the function in order to place the control. I can't override onMeasure to get the measures because my view inherits from another custom view in which this function is final. I tried overriding measureChildren, but it gets called too late (even after onResume on the activity in which the view is placed in). What can I do in order to have the size before the activity calls the function in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to measure your view back in the activity then set properties of the view for it's internal methods to use.

Using a global layout listener has always worked well for me.  It has the advantage of being able to remeasure things if the layout is changed, e.g. if something is set to View.GONE or child views are added/removed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // inflate your main layout here (use RelativeLayout or whatever your root ViewGroup type is
     LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout ) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null); 

     // set a global layout listener which will be called when the layout pass is completed and the view is drawn
     mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               // at this point, the UI is fully displayed
          }
     }
 );

 setContentView(mainLayout);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but as I understand the question was about specific view size not just display size